# Add additional information to payment method

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, payment, magento-2.1.9

I'm trying to add additional data to the `checkmo`  payment method. I then need this additional data appear at the order Endpoint.

I plan on using this as a way of passing over a **sort code** / **account number** for direct debit payments.

I have a system set up that places orders for Magento 2 with the API. A user enters name / address etc and this is sent over using the API.

For payment method I need to pass over **sort code** / **account number**. Rather than creating a custom payment method for this, I would like to try and shoehorn this information into an existing one that won't be used on the actual Magento 2 site.

The issue seems to be actually adding data into this,

The [Swagger documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index.html) seems to have -

```
payment": {
"account_status": "string",
"additional_data": "string",
"additional_information": [
  "string"
],
```

I have tried using this -

```
{
"paymentMethod": {
"method": "checkmo",
"additional_data": {
"sortcode" :"00-00-00",
"account_number" : "12345678"
   }
 }
}
```

But this still comes out at the Endpoint as -

```
"payment": {
    "account_status": null,
    "additional_information": [
        "Check / Money order",
        null,
        null
    ],
```

If I try to use `additonal information` instead -

```
{
"paymentMethod": {
"method": "checkmo",
"additional_information": {
"sortcode" :"00-00-00",
"account_number" : "12345678"
 }
}
```

I get the error

`Message: Property "AdditionalInformation" does not have corresponding setter in class "Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface".`

Is there anyway to add this to an order preferably using checkmo payment method, and then have it appear at the endpoint?

Comment: Ever found a way to set the additional info via the API?

Answer (score 2):

You need to send from frontend to backend all custom information in the `additional_data` node. On the backend side, you need to get data from `additional_data` and store it in the payment `additional_information`.
This [dev guide](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/payments-integrations/base-integration/get-payment-info.html) describes how to do it.

Also, as example, you can look at [Vault\PaymentTokenAssigner](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/app/code/Magento/Vault/Observer/PaymentTokenAssigner.php) or [Braintree\DataAssignObserver](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/app/code/Magento/Braintree/Observer/DataAssignObserver.php).

Comment: Thanks for this.   I was hoping to send the order over using the API though, rather than having to touch Magento. I'll look over the links in more detail and see if I can come to some solution.

Comment: For Web API a data structure will be similar and you need to read data on the server side in the same way.

Comment: @jonijones Example links don't work anymore

Comment: @bets I fixed the URLs, the pointed the 2.2-develop which is not in the repo anymore

Comment: @jonijones Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I've ended up adding a plugin to pass the `additional_information` to the quote payment.

In my `di.xml`:

```
<type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Payment">
    <plugin name="vendorModuleQuotePayment" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\QuotePaymentPlugin"/>
</type>
```

The plugin:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class QuotePaymentPlugin
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Payment $subject
     * @param array $data
     * @return array
     */
    public function beforeImportData(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Payment $subject, array $data)
    {
        if (array_key_exists('additional_information', $data)) {
            $subject->setAdditionalInformation($data['additional_information']);
        }

        return [$data];
    }
}
```

Comment: does it work for graphql too, or theres another method for it?